# Sails.js - passing data to a view

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've recently started learning how to use Sails.js and I came across a small issue.

I have a model called Applicant, as follows:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {     
     name: {
      type: 'STRING',
      required: true
     },

     email: {
      type: 'STRING',
      required: true
     }

  }

};
```

I have built the index action to return all the instances of the Applicant model:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        Applicant.findAll().done(function(err, applicants) {
            res.view({
                apps: applicants
            });
        });
    }
};
```

And this is the view that I am using:

```
<section id="applicants">
    <h1>List of applicants</h1>

    <ul>
        <% for (applicant in apps) { %>
        <li><%= applicant.name %> <%= applicant.email %></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Still, when I load the corresponding URL, I can't see my data displayed.

I have read the Sails.js documentation, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code.

It would be great if someone could help me solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
<%= apps[applicant].name %>
```

It's just like `for` loop works. `applicant` is an index in `apps` array.

**Edit:** Better way is to use javascript array's built in method `forEach`, because this way you avoid cycling through elements, inherited from `apps`'s type (for example, elements, assigned like  this: `apps.__proto__.foo = {name: "bar"}` or  `Array.prototype.foo2 = {name: "pi222"}`).

```
<% apps.forEach(function(applicant)  { %>
    <li><%= applicant.name %> <%= applicant.email %></li>
<% }); %>
```

P.S. Of course this javascript's method (`forEach`) wouldn't work in IE <= 8(if you consider to use it in browser). **But** we are inside NodeJs, which is built on top of V8 engine. So this will work, anyway.