# how to print error message in sails

Tags: validation, sails.js

I have wrote down this code in controller

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){

        res.view('new');
    } ,


    create: function(req, res) {  
        //console.log(req.params.all());
        Employee.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err,user) {
            if (err) {
                //return res.render('new');
                return res.serverError(err, 'new');
            }
            user.save();
            res.json(user);
        });


    },
};
```

and in view new.ejs

```
<form action="/employee/create" method="POST">  
    <h2> Create an account</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">  
    <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
</form>
```

Model: I have implement validation on name

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: { 
     name:{
        type:"string",
        required:true,
        minLength: 2
      },     
  }
};
```

When I insert only 1 string, it redirect me to the view page but done not show error message. How can I display error message on view page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sails.js - passing data to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229908/sails-js-passing-data-to-a-view)

You can use

```
return res.view(pathToView, locals);
```

you can read more detail in here:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
index: function(req, res){

    res.view('new');
} ,


create: function(req, res) {  

    var params=req.allParams();

    if(params.name.length<=2){
          //handle validation
        }
    else {
         Employee.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err,user) {
            if (err) {
              //return res.render('new');
                return res.serverError(err, 'new');
             }
             user.save();
             res.json(user);
        });
  },
 }
};
```

we are handling in this way for small project...